# How to fix White Screen after Splash Screen in React Native for iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-splash-screen

For Android, I made the color of the white screen the same as the Splash Screen color. So how do I change the color of the white screen on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

use react-native-bootsplash or implement splash screen by your own.

you can change the bg color of splash screen using xCode, find and select the .storyboard that is currently used in your project.
from the right side of your x code controls, you will see background prop, from there you can change it.

[image]

Comment: I already changed the background color of Splash Screen. So, after the Splash Screen I'm talking about, there is a white screen that is shown for a short time. I want to change the color of that white screen.

Comment: Alright, I understand. This is what we call a "flashing effect." It occurs when you close your splash screen before completing the initialization process.

If you are using react-navigation along with react-native-bootsplash, you can resolve this issue by moving all your initialization logic to the Navigator's onReady function.

Answer (score 0):

That white screen inbetween splash screen and the App screens is nonetheless a view of the rootviewcontroller, so basically you change that by changing its view's style.

In the AppDelegate.mm file

in the methode:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

at the end you find

```
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
```

that s the rootViewController you need to edit its background

```
rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = YOUR OWN COLOR ;
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
```

**You need to adapt the code to your context and the React Native version if the initialization process changed, but the main idea remains the same**

Comment: My AppDelegate..mm has no reference to anything called rootViewController - this is RN 0.72.  Any clues to help me?